# Many-to-many relationship as list

Tags: django, database

I have a project where I have a `PlayerModel` and a `GameModel`. A player can take part in multiple games and a game can be played with a **variable number** of players.

Thus, it seems obvious to me that this is exactly a many-to-many relationship.

However, in a game I should also store the score of each player. Thus, my first idea would be to design the Game table with two fields, namely a list of player ids and a list (same size) of scores (one for each player taking part in the game).

Thus, I am wondering if my idea is the optimal one in my case.

Comment: there is m2m field available in django

Comment: You could create a new table `games_has_players` with `game_id`,  `player_id` and `score`

Comment: You want a `ManyToManyField` with extra information, as discussed in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in the m2m field.
But in scores it would be a new model

```
Class score:

    Player = ForeignKey

    Game = ForeignKey

    Score = Integer
```

Comment: I think fk=foreign key

Comment: fk is foreign key but its worth mentioning in the answer. Any acronym should be used after once you mention its full one

Comment: Sorry I'm from mobile. Yes fk it's foreign key.